# iPhone 4 stuck on black screen after Jailbreaking with Cydia

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia

I have an iPhone 4, jailbroken, and running iOS 7.1.2. I opened the Cydia app, it appeared to be loading something so I waited. Then the screen turned black. I can still hear sounds such as the charging tone when you plug your iPhone in to your PC and things like that. A few posts have recommended doing some Lock Button and Home Button combo but my lock button is broken and doesn't work.

I can't seem to restore because Find My iPhone is enabled and I need to disable it to be able to restore.

Is there any way I can restore this phone and remove Cydia?

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading redsn0w and creating a DFU mode IPSW. Restore the IPSW with iTunes. Now that your phone is in DFU mode, you can totally wipe the iPhone and restore.

You can download redsn0w [here](https://sites.google.com/a/iphone-dev.com/files/home/redsn0w_mac_0.9.15b3.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

Answer (score 0):

hold down the power and home button untill the apple logo apears this will take 15-20 sec

Comment: He already said the 'lock button' (power button?) was not working. So ... not so much.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was leave my phone on the charger for 10-15 minutes then I pressed my power button (my home button is broken) then my lock screen wallpaper showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Download itools 3.1.9.5 English version you can google it. theres[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.